# ARM assembly GPIO Interface with KEYPAD module

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

Hello I have TM4C123GXL Development Board with MCU TM4C123GH6PM and I have one 4x4 keypad module + 4 switch buttons + 8leds on the module. I connected switches to input ports of my GPIO(B port B0-B3) and 4 leds are connected to my output ports (B4-B7). I think I have done necessary configurations listed below.

```
GPIO_PORTB_DIR      EQU 0x40005400 
GPIO_PORTB_PDR      EQU 0X40005514
GPIO_PORTB_AFSEL    EQU 0x40005420
GPIO_PORTB_DEN      EQU 0x4000551C
IOB                 EQU 0xF0
GPIO_PORTB_LOCK     EQU 0x40005520
GPIO_PORTB_CR       EQU 0x40005524
SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO     EQU 0x400FE608

             AREA   |.text|,    READONLY,   CODE,   ALIGN=2
             THUMB
             EXPORT start

start       PROC
            PUSH    {R0-R1}
            LDR     R1 , =SYSCTL_RCGCGPIO
            MOV     R0 , #0
            ORR     R0 , R0 , #0x02                 ;0000_0010  Only activates B ports' clock.
            STRB    R0 , [R1]                       ;..FE DCBA
            NOP
            NOP
            NOP                                     ;LET CLOCK STABILIZE.
            
            LDR     R1 , = GPIO_PORTB_LOCK          ;Unlock B
            LDR     R0 , =0x4C4F434B                ;Value is not important. (Just ASCII of "LOCK")
            STR     R0 , [R1]                       ;0x40005520 is 00 means it is unlocked.  01 means it is locked. 0x40005524 should be FF for GPIOCR
            
            LDR     R1 , = GPIO_PORTB_AFSEL         
            MOV     R0 , #0
            STRB    R0 , [R1]                       ;Regular I/O will be used.
            
            LDR     R1 , =GPIO_PORTB_DIR            ;Configuration of Port B starts.
            MOV     R0 , #0
            ORR     R0 , #IOB                       ;[B7-B4] = Output   ,    [B3-B0] = Input
            STRB    R0 , [R1]                       ;Modify only B7-B0
            
            LDR     R1 , =GPIO_PORTB_DEN            
            MOV     R0 , #0xFF                      ;Digital I/O is enabled for all pins of port B (B0-B7)
            STRB    R0 , [R1]                       ;Configuration of Port B ends.
            POP     {R0-R1}
            BX LR
            ENDP
                ALIGN
                    END
```

and in my main function I set B7,B6,B5 while B4 was zero as follows

```
            LDR     R1 , =GPIO_PORTB_DATA    ;0x400053FC DATA ADDRESS TO ALL PINS
            MOV     R0 , #0xE0
            STRB    R0 , [R1]
```

When I run the program I was expecting  "E0" in my DATA register address because I am not pressing none of the switches so B0-B3 are all 0, and I initialized outputs as 1110 (E) as above. However, I noticed that It was EF. And here comes my 2 questions.(Sorry if it took so long)

1-)I observed only LED0 on while I was expecting just the other case (LED3,2,1 : ON while LED0 : OFF).

2-)Since I read F(1111 input comes from switches), Is that means my switches are already conducting and when I press them it becomes open circuit?

For both questions, I was expecting just the other cases, and I ended up like this. I think Im missing some point. I will be glad for any help.

Comment: are the switches normally open or normally closed?  if open then do you have one side hooked to ground or hooked to vcc?  if ground do you have the gpio pins pulled up?  after the basics then how do you plan to deal with the bouncing?

Comment: is this an asm question or other?  did you prototype this in C first? or is the programming language not related to the issue?

Comment: Switches look like normally closed because I observed F in DATA register. And when I press S3(corresponds B3) F value decreases to 7 which means B3 is not conducting anymore if switch is pressed. I connected ground and vcc pins. I didn't pull up or down gpıo pins. To handle with debouncing I have a function which inserts some delay

Comment: I think the problem is not related with Programming language.

Comment: the switch is connected on one side to the gpio pin and the other side to...?

Comment: There is a I/O module on key pad for switches. Other side is connected there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224806/discussion-between-blacksmith0040-and-old-timer).

Comment: None of us can help if you cannot describe the circuit or show a schematic or a combination of part numbers if these are off the shelf modules plus a schematic showing how they are connected.